# Is it possible to estimate the angle of attack or flight path angle of a launch vehicle from mission web casts?

Tags: falcon-9, trajectory

The altitude and speed is shown in the web casts of Falcon 9 missions. Is it possible to estimate the angle of attack or flight path angle?

Comment: The angle of attack is the angle between the axis and air flow, for rockets this should always be almost zero.

Comment: @GdD: The Falcon 9 first stage spends several minutes almost "gliding" at a surprisingly low AoA covering a surprisingly large cross range distance. This is done both to decrease heat loads but for RTLS landings also to decrease fuel required for the boost back burn.

Comment: I wasn't considering the fly-back part of the profile when I wrote that comment @JörgWMittag, good point.

Comment: Right at liftoff the alpha is 90 degrees if there is any wind. A fun fact I noticed back in the day when looking at shuttle data.